# What is the Nlog layout renderer for pulling just the message property of an Exception Object?

Tags: c#, nlog

I am starting to use Nlog and running into issues where I want simple data for end users and detailed data for developers.

The simple data would simply be the `Message` property off the `Exception` object, however when I do `${message}` its the same output as `${exception}`. If you inspect the value of this property during an exception, it is usually short and to the point without all the underlying details.

Any way to "filter" down to just this data without directly sending over `exception.Message` as the message parameter? Figured it was built it.

EDIT:

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DBLogger.Error(ex, ex.Message);
            return new List<ApprovalDT>();
        }

      <parameter name="@machineName"    layout="${machinename}" />
  <parameter name="@logged"         layout="${date}" />
  <parameter name="@level"          layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@message"        layout="${message}" />
  <parameter name="@logger"         layout="${logger}" />
  <parameter name="@properties"     layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
  <parameter name="@callSite"       layout="${callsite}" />
  <parameter name="@exception"      layout="${stacktrace}" />
```

Comment: Note: The example has ex.Message passed because that is what i want sent to ${message}. This is the result i intend but figured i am using the renderer wrong and shouldn't have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the NLog docs, [`${exception}` **does** return only the exception's `Message` property by default](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer).

Quote from the link:

> ### Rendering Options
>
> [...]
>
> - **format** - Format of the output. Must be a comma-separated list of exception properties:     Message, Type, ShortType, ToString, Method,
>     StackTrace, Data. This parameter value is case-insensitive. Default:
>     message

---

The docs also say that [`${message}` is the actual log message, **not** the exception's Message property](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Message-Layout-Renderer).

You didn't show your code, so I don't know how you called the logger.
But I suppose that `${exception}` and `${message}` output the same because you didn't pass an actual log message, so NLog simply filled it with the exception's message?
I can't find it in the source code right now, though. Can you show an example how cou call NLog?

Comment: I have added the config section where the data is being passed and also a catch that uses the log.